# Cron job query packet error when starting transaction

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, cron, cron-task

I'm running a PHP script to update some things.  I use PDO to interface with a database.

When I attempted to run `$this->connection->conn->beginTransaction()`, I received the following:
`PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet.`

Immediately following that, another error on the same line: `General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away`.

I've not ever seen either of these errors, but I understand that the packet one often occurs when a packet is larger than what PHP is set to allow.  However, why would it throw this error when beginning a transaction? Can a transaction have that large of a packet when just starting up?

Did the DB just happen to timeout for some reason?

If so, how should I handle this reliably?

Comment: So, are you saying this only happens when launched by cron?  Does it work when run interactively from the shell?

Comment: No I legit only saw it once when running the cron job for the first time automatically via cron.  When testing via the shell, all was good.  I am currently running it from the cron tasks "Run Now" button Plesk gives you, but I figured I should ask to see if I can learn about what may have gone wrong here.

Comment: I ask because the user environment run from cron is not (almost never I should say) the same as the user environment, unless you take some action to configure cron to ingest your profile (paths, etc.).  It's a long shot but it might be a ulimit issue that only happens when being forked from cron, but since Plesk is involved, unless you gain access to the crontab or the scheduler Plesk is using..  hard to say what it could be.

Comment: Do you think running it scheduled vs "run now" would be different in that regard?  Because "run now" is going fine.

Comment: I don't know enough about what Plesk might be doing behind the scenes, such as importing a .profile or .bash_profile when it kicks off the process, to provide any guidance there.  It's a common tool I've seen installed on shared or fractional hardware, I try to avoid using things like that and try to interact at the CLI level whenever possible, so my experience is limited.